# How can I get available license via Google Workspace Admin SDK?

Tags: google-admin-sdk

On Google Admin screen, I can get numbers of available licenses and used licenses shown below:

[image: Google Admin Subscription]

How can I get these numbers via API?

Note: I read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66575862/how-to-get-total-and-current-numbers-of-google-workspace-business-starter-licens) and tried, but not worked well.

-- EDIT: 2021/07/15 --

My request:

https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/reference/rest/v1/customerUsageReports/get
[image]

- date: (few days before now)
- parameters: `accounts:gsuite_unlimited_total_licenses` (comes from [Account Parameters](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/appendix/usage/customer/accounts))

Response from API:

```
{
  "kind": "admin#reports#usageReports",
  "etag": "\"occ7bTD-Q2yefKPIae3LMOtCT9xQVZYBzlAbHU5b86Q/gt9BLwRjoWowpJCRESV3vBMjYMc\""
}
```

Expectation: **I want to get the data same as `2 available, 1132 assigned` as the GUI shows.**

To be honestly, I'm not satisfying even if I can get info via this API, because it seems not responding real-time data like GUI.

Comment: `I read this question and tried, but not worked well.` - what did you try, what were your requests and what was your response?

Comment: @RafaGuillermo I tried this: https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/reference/rest/v1/customerUsageReports/get and find `gsuite_unlimited_total_licenses` or `gsuite_unlimited_used_licenses`, but there's no data in the response.

Comment: Can you show the actual requests you made? And the responses you get? What are you expecting?

Comment: @RafaGuillermo I edited an question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there are 2 ways this information can be obtain, but I can confirm for only one of them.

***1.*** Using the `Report API` that you mentioned.

- **NOTE** : The report is not live data, so you must run the API call with a "date" parameter set at least 2 days before the execution date
- Given that, you would have to run this GET method with the proper date in the `{date}` param

```
GET https://admin.googleapis.com/admin/reports/v1/usage/dates/{date}
```

- Then you would need to parse through the `parameters` to find the desired license you are looking for.
- reference - https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/reference/rest/v1/customerUsageReports#UsageReports
- Here is how it look like after parsing

```
[
    {
        "BoolValue":  null,
        "DatetimeValueRaw":  null,
        "DatetimeValue":  null,
        "IntValue":  12065,
        "MsgValue":  null,
        "Name":  "accounts:gsuite_enterprise_total_licenses",
        "StringValue":  null
    },
    {
        "BoolValue":  null,
        "DatetimeValueRaw":  null,
        "DatetimeValue":  null,
        "IntValue":  12030,
        "MsgValue":  null,
        "Name":  "accounts:gsuite_enterprise_used_licenses",
        "StringValue":  null
    }
]
```

**Important** : The repot will always date 2 day back, so you can get the total number of licenses `gsuite_enterprise_total_licenses` in my example, and then use the `Enterprise License Manager API` to retrieve all currently assigned licenses

- reference https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/licensing/reference/rest

***2.*** Using the `Reseller API`

- Retrieving the information from the reseller point of view  you would need to use the `subscriptions.get` method, providing your `customerId` and `subscriptionId` , calling the following `GET` request:

```
GET https://reseller.googleapis.com/apps/reseller/v1/customers/{customerId}/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}
```

- The response of that would be a `subscriptions` resource, that contains various information about the license and the `Seats object` , which if you expand looks like this :

```
{
  "numberOfSeats": integer,
  "maximumNumberOfSeats": integer,
  "licensedNumberOfSeats": integer,
  "kind": string
}
```

- `numberOfSeats` should be the total amount of licenses and `licensedNumberOfSeats` should be the number of users having that license assigned to them.
- **NOTE** : in order to use this API , the given tenant should have a "fully executed and signed reseller contract" - https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reseller/v1/how-tos/prerequisites
- Reference - https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reseller/reference/rest/v1/subscriptions

Answer (score 1):

#### Answer:

*You can only get the number of assigned licenses using the API, the number available isn't exposed and so does not get returned.*

#### More Information:

Given that you have licenses assigned for your domain, and the user that is querying the API has access to this information, you can retrieve the data with the following request:

```
curl \
  'https://admin.googleapis.com/admin/reports/v1/usage/dates/2021-07-10?parameters=accounts%3Agsuite_unlimited_total_licenses&fields=*&key=[YOUR_API_KEY]' \
  --header 'Authorization: Bearer [YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN]' \
  --header 'Accept: application/json' \
  --compressed
```

While not necessary, I added the parameter `field=*` in order to make sure all data is returned.

This gave me a response as such:

```
{
  "kind": "admin#reports#usageReports",
  "etag": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
  "usageReports": [
    {
      "kind": "admin#reports#usageReport",
      "date": "2021-07-10",
      "etag": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
      "entity": {
        "type": "CUSTOMER",
        "customerId": "C0136mgul"
      },
      "parameters": [
        {
          "name": "accounts:gsuite_unlimited_total_licenses",
          "intValue": "233"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Here you can see that the `intValue` for `accounts:gsuite_unlimited_total_licenses` is 233 - which is reflected in the UI:
[image]

#### Feature Request:

You can however let Google know that this is a feature that is important for access to their APIs, and that you would like to request they implement it.

Google's [Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com) is a place for developers to report issues and make feature requests for their development services, I'd urge you to make a feature request there. The best component to file this under would be the [Google  Admin SDK component](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=191635&template=824102), with the `Feature Request` template.

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to use Reseller API (ran into some authorization issues) and Reports API (contained null values in all relevant attributes). The only way I was able to find how many licenses were remaining was through [Enterprise License Manager API](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/admin-sdk-license-manager).

After getting `assignments`, I used `sdkName` to filter records based on the type of license.

Here is the complete code.

```
function getRemainingGoogleUserLicensesCount() {
    const GOOGLE_USER_LICENSES_TOTAL = 100 // You can find this from Google Admin -> Billing -> Subscriptions 
    const productId = 'Google-Apps';
    const customerId = 'C03az79cb'; // You can find this from this response, https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/manage-users#json-response
    let assignments = [];
    let usedLicenseCount = 0
    let pageToken = null;
    do {
      const response = AdminLicenseManager.LicenseAssignments.listForProduct(productId, customerId, {
        maxResults: 500,
        pageToken: pageToken
      });
      assignments = assignments.concat(response.items);
      pageToken = response.nextPageToken;
    } while (pageToken);
  
    for (const assignment of assignments) {
      if (assignment["skuName"] == "Google Workspace Business Plus") {
        usedLicenseCount += 1
      }
    }
    return GOOGLE_USER_LICENSES_TOTAL - usedLicenseCount
}
```